# How to add preprocessor define globally for "Debug" configuration in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Greetings,
There are a lot of such questions on stackoverflow, but all of them about xcode version < 4, so I asking once more time:

How add preprocessor define globally for "Debug" configuration in XCode 4?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Select project in file browser, go to "build settings" and search for "preprocessor macros". Also .pch file is for global includes as well as global defines.

Comment: Worked. I had to double click on the project from the file browser.

Comment: Nice. So how do you actually add a macro when you're there?

Comment: @dontWatchMyProfile - when in Prefix.pch, just type `#define FOO`, while in build settings - double-tap the value field and type your constant name without `#define` (like `FOO` or `FOO=1`).