# How to determine whether code is running in DEBUG / RELEASE build?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, preprocessor, release

I am making an app that processes sensitive credit card data.

If my code is running in debug mode I want to log this data to the console and make some file dumps.

However on the final appstore version (ie when it is running in release mode) it is essential all of this is disabled (security hazard)!

I will try to answer my question as best I can;  so the question becomes *'Is this solution path the right or best way to do it?'*

```
// add `IS_DEBUG=1` to your debug build preprocessor settings  

#if( IS_DEBUG )  
#define MYLog(args...) NSLog(args)  
#else  
#define MYLog(args...)  
#endif
```

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Check your project's build settings under 'Apple LLVM - Preprocessing', 'Preprocessor Macros' for debug to ensure that `DEBUG` is being set - do this by selecting the project and clicking on the build settings tab. Search for `DEBUG` and look to see if indeed `DEBUG` is being set.

Pay attention though.  You may see DEBUG changed to another variable name such as DEBUG_MODE.

[image: Build Settings tab of my project settings]

then conditionally code for DEBUG in your source files

```
#ifdef DEBUG

// Something to log your sensitive data here

#else

// 

#endif
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer, if i try to make like this: `#ifdef DEBUG NSLog@("Something");#else//#endif`, this doesn't work. How can i initialize a button or log something to the console please, can you edit your question?

Comment: What about in Swift?

Comment: can I change this macro programatically at run time? I want to enable a button that switches to production APIs. On that button, I want to change DEBUG to 0 and display the message that user needs to restart the app. So next time it will use production APIs.

Answer (score 165):

For a solution in Swift please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-swift-language) on SO.

Basically the **solution in Swift** would look like this:

```
#if DEBUG
    println("I'm running in DEBUG mode")
#else
    println("I'm running in a non-DEBUG mode")
#endif
```

Additionally you will need to set the `DEBUG` symbol in `Swift Compiler - Custom Flags` section for the `Other Swift Flags` key via a `-D DEBUG` entry. See the following screenshot for an example:

[image]

Comment: Where do I find Swift Compiler - Custom Flags?

Comment: @confile: I've attached a screenshot that should make clear where to find. Hope it helps!

Comment: Remember this needs to be defined for the specific framework/extension that use it! So if you have a keyboard/today extension define it there. If you have some other kind of framework same thing. This might only be necessary if the main target is objective c...

Comment: thanks, it seems `Other Swift Flags` key won't appear unless you select `All` and `combined` above

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was missing. I had it set for Clang but not Swift.

Comment: See kramer's comment on the linked thread. As for kramer, for me this only worked with `-DDEBUG`

Comment: As of Xcode 9+, you [no longer need to change project settings for new Swift projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74933631/35690).

Answer (score 93):

Apple already includes a `DEBUG` flag in debug builds, so you don't need to define your own.

You might also want to consider just redefining `NSLog` to a null operation when not in `DEBUG` mode, that way your code will be more portable and you can just use regular `NSLog` statements:

```
//put this in prefix.pch

#ifndef DEBUG
#undef NSLog
#define NSLog(args, ...)
#endif
```

Answer (score 48):

Most answers said that  how to set #ifdef DEBUG  and none of them saying how to determinate debug/release build.

My opinion:

1. Edit scheme -> run ->  build configuration :choose debug / release . It can control the simulator and your test iPhone's code status.
2. Edit scheme -> archive ->  build configuration :choose debug / release . It can control the test package app and App Store app 's code status.
   [image]

Comment: Awarded answer!!! it helps me to identify my problem. In my case, I had kept the `Archive` mode to `Debug` and submitted the app to the app store. When checking the result after app download from iTunes it simply does not work. So make sure that `DEBUG/RELEASE` only works when selected respective mode in `Build/Run/Archive`.

Answer (score 40):

**Swift** and **Xcode 10+**

`#if DEBUG` will pass in ANY development/ad-hoc build, device or simulator. It's only false for App Store and TestFlight builds.

Example:

```
#if DEBUG
   print("Not App Store or TestFlight build")
#else
   print("App Store or TestFlight build")
#endif
```

Answer (score 15):

Adding this for people working with **Kotlin** **multiplatform** ios debug mode. Here is how you can determine if the build is debug or release.

```
if (Platform.isDebugBinary) {
     NSLog(message ?: "", "")
}
```

Answer (score 9):

### Swift + Xcode 14 update...

As of Xcode 8, you [should be using "Active Compilation Conditions" instead of "Other Swift Flags"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39435346/35690). As of [Xcode 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-the-swift-language#comment88343449_39435346), Apple already includes the `DEBUG` value for new projects:

[image]

This means **you don't need to change any project settings**, and can simply use `#if DEBUG` immediately:

```
#if DEBUG
  print("something")
#endif
```

Answer (score 8):

zitao xiong's answer is pretty close to what I use; I also include the file name (by stripping off the path of **FILE**).

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define NSLogDebug(format, ...) \
    NSLog(@"<%s:%d> %s, " format, \
    strrchr("/" __FILE__, '/') + 1, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define NSLogDebug(format, ...)
#endif
```

Answer (score 6):

In xcode 7, there is a field under **Apple LLVM 7.0 - preprocessing**, which called "*Preprocessors Macros Not Used In Precompiled...*"
I put **DEBUG** in front of *Debug* and it works for me by using below code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSString* const kURL = @"http://debug.com";
#else
    NSString* const kURL = @"http://release.com";
#endif
```

Answer (score 6):

Just one more idea to detect:

**DebugMode.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DebugMode: NSObject
    +(BOOL) isDebug;
@end
```

**DebugMode.m**

```
#import "DebugMode.h"

@implementation DebugMode
+(BOOL) isDebug {
#ifdef DEBUG
    return true;
#else
    return false;
#endif
}
@end
```

add into header bridge file:

`#include "DebugMode.h"`

usage:

`DebugMode.isDebug()`

It is not needed to write something inside project properties swift flags.

Answer (score 3):

So I found my way here while trying to figure out why my code wasn't executing in my release build, and none of the other answers address how to make
#if RELEASE
work.

I didn't want anything to happen in DEBUG mode, so I just used #if RELEASE, assuming (incorrectly) that it would just work.

#if RELEASE
// do something release specific here
#endif

You can (as of XCode 14 at least) go to the Project -> Combined -> Swift Compiler - Custom Flags (see screenshot below).  Add a RELEASE value to the Release section, and #if RELEASE will work as above.

Note that you don't want to hit the + next to the blank space by release, just double-click the blank space.  If you do, it'll add an "Any Architecture / Any SDK" Line, which makes the RELEASE flag not work properly.

Correct version:
[image]

Incorrect version:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I answered you question, maybe you could try these code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DLOG(xx, ...)  NSLog( \
    @"%s(%d): " \
    xx, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__ \  
    )
#else
#define DLOG(xx, ...)  ((void)0)
#endif
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what that define is doing? It looks neat, but I don't quite get it.  __X__ Usually indicates an Apple reserved macro, whereas PRETTY_FUNCTION indicates something user generated, so the result is confusing

Comment: xx is format string, you can use whatever you want, if it is identical with the previous string.  You can use __FUNCTION__ , but PRETTY_FUNCTION print Objective-C method names. this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300673/is-it-true-that-one-should-not-use-nslog-on-production-code) explain it very well.