# Condition #if DEBUG else if PRODUCTION not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use different environments for my application but facing issues doing it.
It's not the case that `debug` is not working the case is none of the variables are working.

I am attaching a screenshot which will make it easier to understand what is happening.

I am not able to access any of the environments.

I ran this code in `viewDidLoad` of initial view controller of my application and last `else` condition gets executed.

```
#if DEBUG
    print("Environment is debug")
    #elseif debug
    print("Environment is debug")
    #elseif Debug
    print("Environment is Debug")
    #elseif RELEASE
    print("Release")
    #elseif PRODUCTION
    print("Environment is production")
    #elseif PROD
    print("Environment is PROD")
    #else
    print("Environment is can't find")
#endif
```

[image: io]

Adding few more images for better clarity regarding schemes and Xcode settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: tell more about _how_ and _where_ you'd define the compiler flags...?

Comment: Please share your schemes.

Comment: I had added screenshots regarding the compiler flags and configuration.

Comment: There are two schemes in project projectName and projectName-debug but none of them is giving the desired results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode / iOS: How to determine whether code is running in DEBUG / RELEASE build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063100/xcode-ios-how-to-determine-whether-code-is-running-in-debug-release-build)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I did research and setting compiler flags solved the problem.

Earlier they were blank and the way Xcode UI is I got confused how to edit them they looked disabled.

So what you have to do is double tap on the side of the flags or press enter and add the following values as I had attached the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 38):

In my case the issue was solved by adding `DEBUG` as the **debug Active Compilation Condition**. I know it's already specified when you create a new project, but I don't remember if me or another team's member removed it (and why!). So I decided to put it here just in case someone else is facing the same scenario

[image: DEBUG specification in Active Compilation Conditions]

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. It's what Xcode does by default.

Comment: For me it worked, although I needed to set this on a specific target, setting only on the project level didn't help.

Answer (score 11):

`DEBUG` is the only default swift flag on a new project. You can create your own in your project build settings, `Other Swift Flags`.

Otherwise:

```
#if DEBUG
 // This code will be run while installing from Xcode
#else
// This code will be run from AppStore, Adhoc ... 
#endif
```

Comment: My project was written in Obj-C and Swift has been added. In my case, the DEBUG flag was not automatically created and had to be manually added.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the Build Settings are supposed to look for Swift & Objective-C. These are the settings that Xcode creates automatically, so if you're missing DEBUG you can add them again

[image: Adding DEBUG to build settings in Xcode]