# conditional compilation warning for constant

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, constants, definition

## QUESTION

I would like to trigger a warning only if my TESTING is YES. Is this possible? What I have now doesn't work. What should I do?

```
BOOL const TESTING = NO;
#if TESTING == YES
    #warning don't forget to turn testing to NO before upload
#endif
```

## ANSWER

Based on the answer below, here is what worked for me:

```
#define _TESTING // COMMENT THIS OUT TO DISABLE TESTING MODE
#ifdef _TESTING
    BOOL const TESTING = YES;
    #warning don't forget to turn testing to NO for production
#else
    BOOL const TESTING = NO;
#endif
```

Comment: Yeah, the program and macro name spaces are entirely different.  Setting the program value TESTING to NO has no effect on the value of the macro variable TESTING (though the value of the macro variable is substituted the other direction, in a text replacement pass before the actual compiler even sees the program).

Comment: @HotLicks: So if he's using his `TESTING` bool in the program to say, show an alert view or something, he'll still need to keep the `BOOL const TESTING = NO;` to make the program code recognize it, correct?  So he will have to both comment out the `#define TESTING` and set `BOOL const TESTING = NO` when he releases, correct?

Comment: He should not name his BOOL variable TESTING, or the macro phase will replace it with NO, resulting in some mysterious compilation errors.  Thus, always use all UPPER-CASE for macro variables, and never use all upper case for program variables.  But he can have the macro variable TESTING control the setting of his Testing variable, with ifdefs or other techniques.

Comment: Note that, as stated just above, it's a bad idea to have an all UPPER-CASE program variable name.

Comment: Your answer is perfect, Jackson. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing what you have with

```
#ifdef TESTING
  #warning //... warning here
  BOOL const testingBool = YES;
#else
  BOOL const testingBool = NO;
#endif
```

Then, you need to add TESTING as a "Preprocessor Macro" in your Target's Build Settings (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851152/how-do-i-define-preprocessor-macros-in-xcode-4) question for more details on how to do that).

Comment: Better still, define `TESTING` in the build configuration so it's global and easily changed.

Comment: @trojanfoe: thanks for the suggestion, edited answer (with link that describes how to do set this up).