# Macro undefined error while building a plugin

Tags: c++, macos, macros, cross-platform

I am working on a plugin in which I need to `#include` a header file (let's say `some_file.h`) which in turn includes `environ.h`. Now, when I build my plugin, the build fails with some errors in the `environ.h` file and some other dependent files. Here's a code sample from `environ.h` where the error is occurring:

```
#ifndef PLATFORM
#ifdef WIN_ENV
#define PLATFORM "winpltfm.h"
#elif __OS2__
#define PLATFORM "os2pltfm.h"
#elif defined(unix) || defined(__unix)
 #define PLATFORM "UnixPlatform.h"
#else
#error You must define the PLATFORM macro     <------- Error-1
#endif
#endif

#include PLATFORM                             <------- Error-2
```

The Error-1 is: `#error you must define the platform macro` and Error-2 is easy to guess: `Expected <filename> or "filename"`.

The strange thing is that some other plugin where `some_file.h` is included works fine i.e. builds successfully. This made me think that there must be some build settings which might be different.

Can anyone suggest what should be done in such a case to remove the errors from the `environ.h` header file?

Note: I am working on MAC OS X in Xcode.

Comment: `__OS2__` isn't getting defined.  Is it expected to be defined by the compiler?  For a test, you can added a `#define __OS2__` before your `#include "environ.h"`, and see the problem go away for that translation unit.

Comment: Simple `#define __OS2__` starts complaining even more. So, I added `#define __OS2__ 1` before including the `some_file.h`. Now, it says `os2pltfm.h file not found`. Is this the standard file for OSX?

Comment: You're missing a define around `__OS2__`, which is why defining it to `1` worked.  I'm not familiar enough with Xcode to recommend a solution, but it would seem that you need to pass the path to os2pltfm.h to your compiler.  Also a define switch for `__OS2__`.

Comment: What do you mean by "switch for `__OS2__`"?

Answer (score 0):

I continued my comments to this answer so it's easier to explain...

**First**, instead of `#elif __OS2__` it should be `#elif defined(__OS2__)` that's why during your test `#define __OS2__` didn't work, but `#define __OS2__ 1` did.

**EDIT:** From your comments you noted that environ.h is a standard file, but it seems odd how they are checking for the OS2 define.  They are forcing it to be defined to a value rather than just being defined.

**Second**, as evident from your test, the compiler isn't defining `__OS2__` for you, and there might be another header that is, but isn't currently included in the tranlation unit that picks up `some_file.h`.  If you've confirmed that **OS2** isn't defined by another header file in your project you can define a macro for the preprocessor by following these steps given by this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7851299/2705293):

> The build setting you need to change is called 'Preprocessor Macros'
>   and it can be found in the 'Build Settings' tab of the Project
>   Settings pane (use the search box to find it). Select each target in
>   turn in the left-hand side of the Project Settings pane then modify
>   the Preprocessor Macros setting.
>
> The setting is specified as a space-separated list of preprocessor
>   macros in the form 'foo' or 'foo=bar'.

**Third**, it seems your include path to `os2pltfm.h` is wrong or missing in your compiler settings.

You can include the file following the instructions given in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14153027/2705293):

> All you have to do is add the -I flag to your build setting under
>   "Other C Flags"
>
> So in your target's build setting search for "Other C Flags" and add
>   -I/path-to-include/

Comment: This (`environ.h`) is a standard file, so I guess there is nothing wrong with the file data. There may be something wrong with the compiler settings. Also, I am able to get this `os2pltfm.h` file anywhere. The strange thing that I talked about is that including `some_file.h` in some other plugin works without any complaints.

Comment: I looked for the preprocessor macros in the other plugin but could not find this specific macro defined there..

Comment: Are these other plugins you have written? Or third parties?  If they are third party, it's possible the authors were adding the OS2 definition as a argument to the compiler rather than actually putting it into code.  That is a common practice to make the code portable.

Comment: Yes, these plugins have been written by our team only. So, by adding macro definition as an argument, you mean adding it in the build settings, right?

Comment: Correct.  Ultimately it turns into a -D__OS2__ switch used by gcc/g++ if I understand the backend of XCode correctly.

Comment: I added to my answer, how to add an include path.