# Create and access "debugMode" variable across different classes

Tags: objective-c, class, variables

I am trying to create a Boolean variable, debugMode, and access it across several different classes. This way I can set it's value once in my ViewController, and will be able to access it in my different classes (subclasses of SKScene) to show framerate, log physics values, etc.

I have read that I need to create an instance of my class? I don't see how that applies in this program.

I am new to objective-c and would greatly appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default solution is a preprocessor define, this is set by default in xcode projects.

So, in the source you can put

```
#ifdef DEBUG
// code that should only run in Debug Configuration
#endif
```

Comment: What if I need to run debug code elsewhere? For example, in each one of my scenes to determine whether to show framerate.

Comment: What do you mean with "elsewhere", you could use this in any source code file. It is processed by the preprocessor of the compiler.

Comment: BTW: For building the release you must add a second scheme in the project that uses the release configuration.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. How would I run this in another file?

Answer (score -2):

So if I get you right you want an instance of a given class that you can use across the whole of your application without losing the state of the class but this should only exist in the `DEBUG` version of your code?

Ok we can do this using a Singleton Pattern mixed with the `#ifdef DEBUG` to determine whether in debug mode or not.

**DebugManager.h**

```
// Our Debug Class that we have just made up.
// Singleton class
@interface DebugManager : NSObject

// Some properties that we want on the class
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *debugName;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDate *instanceCreatedOn;

// a method for us to get the shared instance of our class
+ (id)sharedDebugManager;

@end
```

**DebugManager.m**

```
#import "DebugManager.h"

@implementation DebugManager

// Create a shared instance of our class unless one exists already
+ (id)sharedDebugManager
{
    static DebugManager *sharedDebugManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedDebugManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }); 

    return sharedDebugManager;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        debugName = @"Debug Instance";
        instanceCreatedOn = [NSDate new];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Now that we have a Singleton class setup we can add the below line to our `*-Prefix.pch` which will give us an instance of our `DebugManager` class that we can use throughout our app.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    DebugManager *manager = [DebugManager sharedDebugManager];
#endif
```

Just remember that when you want to use your `manager` instance you will need to wrap it in `#ifdef DEBUG` because when running in production this will not see the instance of `manager` anymore. So make sure you do:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
     NSLog(@"The DebugManagers instance name is %@", [manager debugName]);
#endif
```

Don't forget to add your preprocessor macro in xcode under your `Build Settings` follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851152/how-do-i-define-preprocessor-macros-in-xcode-4) answer to find out how to do that

If you have any questions just ask below.

Comment: I think we're on the same page. Just to clarify, I would set the value of debugMode to YES at the launch of the application. Then when my application runs a particular scene, I could do something along the lines of "if (debugMode) {log the coordinate of the player, etc}". I understand the syntax would be much different.

Comment: What you need to do to get the `DEBUG` variable is go to your `Build Settings` search for `Prepocessor Macros` and add `DEBUG=1` under just the `Debug` option **NOT** the release option.

Comment: Got it. I just set DEBUG = 1, and then, as you said, used #ifdef in order to log certain messages. Thank you for the informative response and I apologize if I wasn't clear in the beginning. Also, how would I switch to the release version?

Comment: To switch to your release version you need to change the scheme version to release.

Comment: When I go to product > scheme, there is only one option (the name of my project). How would I change the version? Sorry, I'm new to Xcode.